# a/b*2 на ассемблере

Tags: c, ассемблер, html

Пытаюсь решить пример на ассемблере a/b*2 используя вставки. Программа зависает, виной тому строчка с div. Не понимаю в чем ошибка.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//_________a/b*2___________
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int a=100,b=5,c=2;
int res;
__asm
{
    mov al,b;
    mul c;
    mov dx,ax;
    mov al,0;
    mov ax,a;
    div dx;
    mov res,ax;
}
printf("%d\n",res);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Каким компилятором пользуетесь? просто у современных компиляторов `int` обычно 4-байтный...

Comment: Использую Pelles C

Comment: У вас в первой строке вообще содержимое `ax` не определено (`ah` не инициализируется). Поэтому в результате умножения на `int` получится вовсе не `5*2`, а что угодно. Дальше вообще непонятно зачем `mov al,0`, если тут же перезаписывается весь `ax`... И снова плюха: `div dx` работает с парой `ax:dx`, а не с `ax`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` вообще-то делит `dx:ax` (`edx:eax`) на что-то, так что я бы делал так (я пишу для 32-разрядного кода для VC++)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a=100,b=5,c=2;
    int res;
    __asm
    {
        mov eax,b
        mul c         ; eax <- b*c
        mov ebx,eax   ; ebx <- b*c
        xor edx,edx
        mov eax,a     ; edx:eax <- a  
        div ebx       ; eax <- a/(b*c) = 100/(5*2)
        mov res,eax
    }
    printf("%d\n",res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а что такое " xor edx,edx;"? и почему вы используете регистры типа eax, а не ax?

Comment: Обнуление edx, а регистры использую 32-битные, потому как использую 32-битный `int` в VC++.

Comment: и последний вопрос, не понимаю, почему в вашем коде вместо ebx нельзя использовать edx? знаю, что вопрос глупый, но я только сегодня начал изучать ассемблер

Comment: Потому что `div rr`, делит `edx:eax` на `rr`. По определению. Так что `edx` вообще-то не может быть делителем.

Answer (score 1):

Стоит упомянуть, что если делитель является константой, то можно заменить деление `n/5` на комбинацию умножения и сдвигов, что может выполняться гораздо быстрее. К примеру, для `uint32_t` аргумента на [x86-64 gcc](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Auint32_t+div5(uint32_t+a)+%7B%0A++return+a+/+5+*+2%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:35.969664138678226,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g7snapshot,filters:(b:'0',directives:'0'),options:'-O2+'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7+(snapshot)',t:'0')),k:64.03033586132177,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
/// "n / 5 * 2"
uint32_t div5mul2(uint32_t n)
{
  __asm__ ("movl    $0xcccccccd, %%edx\n\t"
           "mull    %%edx\n\t"        // edx:eax = edx * eax
           "shrl    $2, %%edx\n\t"    // edx >>= 2 (логический сдвиг)
           "leal    (%%edx,%%edx), %%eax\n\t" :  "+a" (n) : : "edx", "cc");
  return n;
}
```

Здесь `n / 5` заменяется на `(n * 0xcc_cc_cc_cd) >> 34` формулу, что  работает для всего диапазона `uint32_t`. `mul + shr` является оптимизированным аналогом, как правило, дорогой инструкции `div`:

```
uint32_t div5mul2_div(uint32_t n)
{
  uint32_t b = 5;
  __asm__ ("xorl    %%edx, %%edx\n\t"
           "divl    %1\n\t"
           "addl    %%eax, %%eax\n\t" : "+a" (n) : "r"(b) : "edx", "cc");
  return n;
}
```

Компиляторы умеют самостоятельно оптимизировать деление целого на константу и можно получить аналогичный код для `int32_t` и других случаев. Чтобы поделить множество чисел на делитель, который не известен во время компиляции, можно [libdivide библиотеку](http://libdivide.com/) попробовать (автор заявляет от 2 до 16 раз улучшение в производительности). Вот [блог автора, с введением в теорию](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/labor-of-division-episode-i.html).

[Reciprocal Multiplication](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/divide.html) подход известен давно (с 1980x). Другие ссылки:

- вводное описание [частного случая для  `x / 5`](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/integer-division-by-constant/)
- подробное описание похожих алгоритмов, используемых в GMP: ["Improved division by invariant integers" by Niels Möller and Torbjörn Granlund (2010)](https://gmplib.org/~tege/division-paper.pdf)
- ["Hacker's Delight" (2003) книга](http://www.hackersdelight.org/). Ссылка на главу доступна на [Computing the Multiplicative Inverse for Optimizing Integer Division](http://www.flounder.com/multiplicative_inverse.htm).

---

Полный пример для переменного делителя:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int32_t a = 100, b = 5;
  /// a = a / b * 2
  __asm__ (
    // AssemblerTemplate
    "cltd                \n\t" // sign-extend eax into edx:eax
                               //   edx = (eax < 0) ? 0b1...1 : 0...0
    "idivl   %1          \n\t" // eax = (edx:eax) / %1
    "addl    %%eax, %%eax\n\t" // eax += eax
    // : OutputOperands
    : "+a"( a )
    //  [ : InputOperands ]
    : "r" ( b )
    //  [ : Clobbers ] ]
    : "edx", "cc"
     );
  return printf("%" PRId32 "\n", a) < 0;
}
```

Использование:

```
$ gcc *.c && ./a.out
```