# Проверка чередования четных и нечетных цифр в числе

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Ищем сумму тех натуральных чисел из интервала `[a,b]`, в которых четные и не четные цифры чередуются.

Как проверить **чередование четных и нечетных цифр**?

```
#include <iostream>

/* run this program using the console pauser
   or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int S = 0;
    cout << "a=";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b=";
    cin >> b;

    for (a; a < b; a = a + 1)
    {
        while (a > 0)
        {
            c = a % 10;
            if (true)
            {
                if (c % 2 == 0)
                {
                }
                else;
                {
                    if (c % 2 != 0);
                }
            }
            S = S + c;
        }
    }
    cout << "suma=" << S << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Взять остаток от деления на 2. Если итерация не первая - сравнить с  запомненным с предыдущей итерации. Если равны - вернуть False. Иначе запомнить остаток. Сравнить текущее число с нулём. Если равно - вернуть True. Иначе поделить целочисленно на 10. Повторить с самого начала. В С++ не силён, кодом пиши сам..

Comment: Это надо сохранить, отлить в граните! От `if (true) {...}` до `if (...) {} else;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Одно из самых оптимальных решений по скорости работы. Сложность - порядка длины числа (десятичного логарифма).

```
unsigned long long P10[] = {1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000,1000000000, 10000000000LL};
unsigned long long P5[] =  {1,5 ,25 ,125 ,625  ,3125  ,15625  ,78125   ,390625   ,1953125   , 9765625};

unsigned long long P45[2][9] =
   {4,45,454,4545,45454,454545,4545454,45454545, 454545454,
    5,54,545,5454,54545,545454,5454545,54545454, 545454545};

unsigned int getCount(long long a){
   int r = 0;
   for (;a >0; a/=10,r++) ;
   return r;
}

unsigned int getFirst(long long a){
   for (;a >= 10; a/=10) ;
   return a;
}

unsigned long long getFullDp(int count, bool isOdd){
    if (count <= 0)
        return 0;
    return P45[!isOdd][count-1]*P5[count];
}

unsigned long long getCountDp(long long a, int flag, int count){
    if (!a && !count)
        return 1;
    if (!count)
        return 0;
    count--;
    int first = a/P10[count];
    long long res = 0;
    for (int i=!flag;i<first; i+=2)
        res+= P5[count];
    if (first&1 ^ flag == 1)
        res+= getCountDp(a - P10[count]*first, first&1, count);
    return res; 
}

unsigned long long getDP(unsigned long long a, int flag, int count){
    if (!count)
        return 0;
    count--;
    int first = a/P10[count];
    long long res = 0;
    for (int i=!flag;i<first; i+=2)
        res+= P10[count]*i*P5[count]+getFullDp(count, i&1);
    if (first&1 ^ flag == 1)
        res+= P10[count]*first*getCountDp(a - P10[count]*first, first&1, count) 
            + getDP(a - P10[count]*first, first&1,count);
    return res;
}

unsigned long long getDP(unsigned long long a){
    if (!a)
        return 0;
    int count = getCount(a) - 1;
    int first = getFirst(a);
    long long res = getFullDp(count,0) + getFullDp(count,1);
    for (int i=1;i<count;i++)
        res += getFullDp(i,1);
    for (int i=1;i<first; i++)
        res+= P10[count]*i*P5[count]+getFullDp(count, i&1); 
    res+= P10[count]*first*getCountDp(a - P10[count]*first, first&1,count) 
        + getDP(a - P10[count]*first, first&1,count);
    return res; 
}
```

Привожу также тестирующую обвязку (полное тестирование до 1 миллиарда, осторожно с переполнениями int-а), тестовый код из решения @Harry.

```
bool alter(unsigned int n)
{
    bool last = n&1;
    n /= 10;
    while(n)
    {
        bool now = n&1;
        if (now == last) return false;
        last = now;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return true;
}


int main() {

        long long sum = 0;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= 100000000; ++i){
           if (alter(i)) 
            sum += i;
           long long r = getDP(i);
           if (sum != r)
            cout << i<<" "<<sum<<" "<<r<<endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Теперь как это работает)

1. Мы разрешаем числу начинаться с 0.
2. Мы замечаем что на промежутке [1,10^k] таких чисел будет 5^k, а их сумма нетрудно вычисляется через усреднение (там появятся средние 454545... и 545454...)
3. Учимся считать суммы на таких интервалах (метод `getFullDp`)
4. Учимся учитывать что в числе может быть меньше цифр (метод `getDP(long long a)` цикл `res += getFullDp(i,1);`
5. Понимаем что если мы фиксируем 1 цифру, то задача опять сводится к нахождению суммы на подобном интервале и нахождению количества таких чисел
6. Кодим нахождение количества (метод `getCountDp`)
7. Кодим остальное
8. Боремся с такими багами как неправильно учтённый 0 или что-то подобное.
9. Для вычисления на интервале [a,b] нужно писать `getDP(b) - getDP(a-1)`

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы узнать, чередуется ли чётность десятичных цифр в числе, можно простую рекурсивную функцию определить:

```
bool interleaved_digits(int n, bool parity)
{
  return (n == 0) or (parity != (n & 1) and interleaved_digits(n / 10, not parity));
}

/// whether odd and even digits in *n* are interlaced
bool interleaved_digits(int n)
{
  return interleaved_digits(n / 10, n & 1);
}
```

- если число `n` имеет одну цифру, то при первой проверке `n == 0` истинно (после `n / 10`) и функция `true` возвращает
- если в числе больше одной цифры, то нечётность предыдущей цифры, сохранённая в `parity`, сравнивается с нечётностью текущего числа,  возвращаемого `n & 1` выражением и если [чётность идущих подряд чисел совпадает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/619377/23044) (они не чередуются), то сразу `false` возвращается
- иначе текущая цифра отбрасывается (с помощью `n / 10`) и возвращается чередуется ли чётность цифр в оставшемся числе (с помощью рекурсивного вызова).

`gcc`, `clang` компиляторы достаточно умные, чтобы [заменить деление на константу (`10`)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632815/23044) на умножение, что может быть гораздо эффективней и [заменить хвостовой рекурсивный вызов на цикл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519147/23044). Вот [пример генерируемого ассемблера для x86-64 gcc 7](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'bool+interleaved_digits(int+n,+bool+parity)%0A%7B%0A++return+(n+%3D%3D+0)+or+(parity+!!%3D+(n+%26+1)%0A++++++++++++++++++++++and+interleaved_digits(n+/+10,+not+parity))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.48677248677248,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2+',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:47.51322751322752,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

Чтобы сумму таких чисел в заданном диапазоне `[a, b]` найти:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cerr << "Enter a b: ";
  int a, b;
  if (not (std::cin >> a >> b))
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  long long sum = 0;
  for ( ; a <= b; ++a)
    if (interleaved_digits(a))
      sum += a;
  std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

Пример:

```bsh
$ g++ sum-interleaved.cc
$ echo 1 20 | ./a.out
Enter a b: 115
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так?

```
bool alter(unsigned int n)
{
    bool last = n&0x01;
    n /= 10;
    while(n)
    {
        bool now = n&0x01;
        if (now == last) return false;
        last = now;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = a; i <= b; ++i)
    {
        if (alter(i)) sum += i;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

P.S. Ваш код с перлами вроде точки с запятой после `else` даже не рассматриваю...

P.P.S. Добавив внешний цикл в 1000 повторений и значения `a=100000` и `b=1000000`, получил время работы своей программы примерно 2.1 с; у @jfs при тех же условиях примерно 4.3 с. Visual C++ 2015, с оптимизацией.

Comment: знаю про точку с запятой, просто дев с++ не компилирует без етого

Comment: Без чего? Без точки с запятой после `else`? :O Т.е. он теоретически не разрешает ничего писать после `else`? :)

Comment: пишет, что [Error] expected ' ; ' before '}' token ,там где `елсе`

Comment: что такое `alter(i)`?

Comment: А посмотреть на первую строчку? :) Функция проверки.

Comment: Спасибо:) а ето что значит `n&0x01`?

Comment: @AwesomeMan, это проверка на четность. Используется знание машинного представления целых чисел в памяти. Младший бит 0 -- четное.

Comment: @Harry а я думал тут ДП использовать) идеальная же динамика по числу, прямо из книги.

Comment: @pavel Так в чем проблемы? я всего лишь дал простейшее решение, но с огромным интересом ознакомился бы с вашим. Если вам не трудно и не жаль времени - то очень бы хотелось посмотреть...

Comment: @Harry на всякий случай, `n & 0x01` это гарантируется стандартом быть критерием четности?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Для `unsigned int` - да. Для знаковых - не уверен, но вряд ли вы встретите такую архитектуру+компилятор, где нет...

Comment: @Harry написал. Можете подправить код, если сможете его более понятным сделать)

Comment: @pavel Спасибо! Очень интересно, покопаюсь вечером по свободе.