# как проверить числа из интервала (а;b) на чeредование четных и нечетных цифр?

Tags: python

```
a = int(input("a="))
b = int(input("b="))
k = 0
i = a
while i < b:
    z = i
    if i > 0:
       p = 0
       while z != 0:
          p = z % 10
          z = z//10
          if p % 2 == 0:
             m = z % 10
             z = z // 10
             if m % 2 != 0:
                k += 1
                print(i)
             else:
                break

    i += 1
print(k)
```

интервал

```
a=1234
b=1245
(1235,1236,1237,1238,1239,1240,1241,1242,1243,1244)
```

числа в которых чередуются четные и нечетные цифры:

```
1236,1238
количество: 2
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы уточнить вопрос?
проверить на что? как? объяснить свою попытку.
Вам нужно количество четных и нечетных чисел на интервале или что?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Проверка чередования четных и нечетных цифр в числе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/634724/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Если преобразовать число в строку, то можно достаточно просто проверить число на чередование четных и нечетных цифр - заменяем каждую цифру на `1` если она четная или на `0` в противном случае. Далее проверяем строку на наличие повторяющихся единиц или нулей:

```
def chk(n):
    s = ''.join([str(int(int(x)%2==0)) for x in str(abs(n))])
    return ('00' not in s and '11' not in s)
```

потом просто просуммировать:

```
print(sum(chk(x) for x in range(a+1, b)))
```

напечатает:

```
2
```

---

функция для проверки на чередование четных и нечетных цифр в числе, написанная  "в лоб" (без преобразования числа в строку):

```
def chk(n):
    n = abs(n)
    prev = None
    while (n > 0):
        n,b = divmod(n, 10)
        if prev is not None:
            if prev == (b % 2 == 0):
                return False
        prev = (b % 2 == 0)
    return True
```

---

при помощи регулярных выражений:

```
import re

def chk(n):
    return re.search(r'(?:[02468]{2,}|[13579]{2,})', str(abs(n))) is None
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы узнать чередуются ли чётные/нечётные цифры в числе, можно адаптировать простое рекурсивное решение [(см. объяснение)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/634752/23044):

```
def interleaved_digits(n):
    def f(n, parity):
        return (n == 0) or (parity != (n & 1) and f(n // 10, not parity))
    return f(n // 10, n & 1)
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/Pbqv3L):

```
>>> [*filter(interleaved_digits, range(1234, 1245))]
[1234, 1236, 1238]
>>> len(_)
3
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
def interleaved_digits(n):
    def f(n, parity):
        return (n == 0) or (parity != (n & 1) and f(n // 10, not parity))
    return f(n // 10, n & 1)

# try your own input    
from browser import document, html
@document["mybutton"].bind("click")
def on_click(event):
    a = int(document['a'].value)
    b = int(document['b'].value)
    lst = list(filter(interleaved_digits, range(a,b)))
    document <= html.P(f'[{a}, {b}): {len(lst)}: {lst}')
</script><div><label for="a">a: <input id="a" value="1234"></div><div><label for="b">b: <input id="b" value="1245"></div><button id="mybutton">Запустить</button></body>
```